# How to query on multiple collections in MongoDB based on a condition?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, apache-nifi

I have a scenario, need to import big documents(.xlsx), then converting to CSV and then to JSON, then using putMongo using Nifi.

Now I want to query on these collections(2),  like any select SQL query with where clause ...

the SQL query:

```
select t1.X, t1.Y_DT,t1.Z,t1.adj,t1.bjc,t1.jbc,t1.mnk,t2.adj1,t2.bjc1,t2.jbc1,t2.mnk1 from inpt1 t1, input2 t2 where t1.X = t2.X AND t1.Y_DT=t2.Y_DT AND t1.Z = t2.Z;
```

A similar MongoDB query needed…,

How to do using Nifi? something like above.

Comment: You need to use `$lookup` operator in aggregator. Please follow the link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/ and try it yourself and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `$lookup` operator works as ngShravil.py suggested in the comment, you'd want to write an aggregation query and run it with `RunMongoAggregation` in NiFi.